# Use external variables like bash when run perl script

Tags: perl

The question is simple, but I haven't found the answer on Google.

How do I run in perl something like this?

```
[$] VARIABLE=foo ./script.sh
```

I have a perl script (Nvidia Cuda installer, for example) with hardcoded variables in the script, but I want to set that variables when I run the script instead of editing the script.

In bash it's like posted above, but I don't know how make this work on perl.

Is it possible to do this?

Greetings.

EDIT: For clarification: this is a sniplet of the install-linux.pl script:

```
sub can_add_for_all_users()
{
    my $filename = "/usr/share/applications/.nvidiatoolkitinstall";
    system("touch $filename 2>/dev/null");
    if (-f $filename)
    {
        system("rm $filename");
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I want to run something like this:

```
[$] filename="/tmp/.nvidiatoolkitinstall" perl install-linux.pl -destdir="${pkgdir}" -prefix="/opt/cuda" -noprompt -nosymlink
```

But this not works

I can do edit the script with sed:

```
[$] sed 's|/usr/share/applications/.nvidiatoolkitinstall|/tmp/.nvidiatoolkitinstall|g' -i install-linux.pl
```

but i want parser the variable to perl instead, like bash can do

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for "how to read environment variables with perl". Perl have `%ENV` hash, which keeps all these variables. You can simply access them with `$ENV{'VARIABLENAME'}`. Simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print $ENV{'VARIABLE'};
```

and than `VARIABLE=blahblah script.pl` returns `blahblah`.

Answer (score 0):

```
local $ENV{VARIABLE} = 'foo';
system('./script.sh');
```